# Filter Views results by users mobile OS

Tags: 7, views

I'm building a mobile website with Drupal 7 and I need to filter articles displayed using Views by visitors mobile OS. If visitor is using Android phone - I would like display only articles with "Android" tag, etc. Visitors with "other" mobile OS'es will get "no results" message.
What is the best approach to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module with this add-on: [Context Useragent](http://drupal.org/project/context_useragent)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) (or just Page Manager from [ctools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools)), you can use the [Mobile Detect](http://drupal.org/project/mobile_detect) module if you also enable the Mobile Detect ctools sub-module.

Make your view over the content type.  Then add a pane display, and add a filter for your device term.  Add more panes as needed.

Use Page Manager to make a page.  Make variants for each of the mobile devices that you need.  Set the access options to whatever you need.  Then set the selection rule to use the mobile detect device type.  You will get a modal with a whole bunch of devices.  Configure as needed.  Then for the content, add the pane you created above.  Add additional variants as needed.

Full disclosure: I am the author/maintainer for Mobile Detect, but this is one of the scenarios I envisioned when I made this module.

Comment: is Mobile Detect module stable enough to be used in production?

Comment: I think so.  New features will mainly appear in new sub-modules.  It is being developed to support a new website we are developing, but we don't have it in a production site yet.